# PDFbox, IOException: "COSStream has been closed..."

Tags: java, pdfbox

When converting a PDF to an image, adding this image to a new PDF document and printing text on top of it, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.getFilteredStream(COSStream.java:179)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1147)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.accept(COSStream.java:298)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject.accept(COSObject.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:538)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteBody(COSWriter.java:450)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1031)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:401)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1314)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:991)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:963)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:951)
    at org.foo.bar.experimental.printOCROverlay(PDFDocument.java:343)
```

I have text documents that were scanned and OCR processed. Since the OCR quality is of inconsitent quality from document to document I want to check it's quality by just printing the real/OCR text on top of the original PDF.

I wrote a very linear method, parsed the whole text first, then extracted all pages from the original PDF and finally create a new PDF document, draw the image and print the text.
I found several posts online, where the error could be traced back to a PDF document being closed too early. But I also get this error when moving all `close()`-calls to the end.

Below is the method printing out the document. I've pinpointed the error source down to the part where I print the text (the inner `for`-loop, starting with the comment line `// Draw extracted text`), cause when I remove the part from `contentStream.beginText()` to `contentStream.endText()` everything works. But I just don't get what I have to change in order to make it work.

Btw, I'm using PDFBox 2.

```
protected void printOCROverlay() throws IOException {

    if (_listOfWords == null || _listOfWords.isEmpty()) {
        __log.error("No words in PDF.");
        return;
    }

    // Get all pages as image
    PDDocument pdfDocIn = PDDocument.load(new File(_inputFileName_PDF));
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdfDocIn);
    ArrayList<BufferedImage> pageImages_List = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    for (int n = 0; n < pdfDocIn.getNumberOfPages(); n++) {
        BufferedImage pageImage = null;
        try {
            pageImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(n, RENDER_DPI, ImageType.RGB);
            pageImages_List.add(pageImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    pdfDocIn.close();

    // Init new pdf-doc
    PDDocument pdDocument = new PDDocument();

    // Init first page
    PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
    pdDocument.addPage(page);

    // Init content stream
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, page, true, true);
    contentStream.setStrokingColor(_lightGrayColor);    // Bounding box color

    // Draw first image
    PDImageXObject pdImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(pdfDocIn, pageImages_List.get(_listOfWords.get(0).page-1));
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, PDRectangle.A4.getWidth(), PDRectangle.A4.getHeight());


    for (int i = 0; i < _listOfWords.size(); i++) {
        DocElements.Word currentWord = _listOfWords.get(i);

        // Create new page
        if (i > 0 && currentWord.page > _listOfWords.get(i-1).page) {
            contentStream.close();

            // Create new page, init new content stream
            page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
            pdDocument.addPage(page);
            contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, page, true, true);
            contentStream.setStrokingColor(_lightGrayColor);

            // Draw image of next page
            pdImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(pdfDocIn, pageImages_List.get(currentWord.page-1));
            contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, PDRectangle.A4.getWidth(), PDRectangle.A4.getHeight());
        }

        // Draw bounding box
        contentStream.addRect(currentWord.bBox);
        contentStream.stroke();

        // Draw extracted text
        contentStream.beginText();
        for (int c = 0; c < currentWord.word.size(); c++) {
            TextPosition currChar = currentWord.word.get(c);
            PDFont wordFont = currChar.getFont();
            contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(_ocrColor);
            contentStream.setFont(wordFont, 1.0f);
            contentStream.setTextMatrix(currChar.getTextMatrix());

            // Sometimes there are unprintable symbols...
            try {
                contentStream.showText(currChar.toString());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iEx) {
                __log.debug("Non-supported character [IllegalArgumentException]: " + currChar.toString());
                contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(_warnColor);
                contentStream.setFont(_font, 1.0f);
                contentStream.showText("[?]");
            } catch (NullPointerException nEx) {
                __log.debug("Non-supported character [NullPointerException]: " + currChar.toString());
                contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(_warnColor);
                contentStream.setFont(_font, 1.0f);
                contentStream.showText("[?]");
            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException usEx) {
                __log.debug("Non-supported character [UnsupportedOperationException]: " + currChar.toString());
                contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(_warnColor);
                contentStream.setFont(_font, 1.0f);
                contentStream.showText("[?]");
            }
        }
        contentStream.endText();
    }
    contentStream.close();

    String outputPath = _outputFolder + getFileNameWithoutExt(_inputFileName_PDF) + "_ocr.pdf";
    __log.info("Trying to save reconstructed file to: " + outputPath);
    pdDocument.save(outputPath);

    pdDocument.close();
}
```

Comment: Based on your stack trace, you are using a version from mid July. Please get a current snapshot or the RC1, try again, and if it still happens, edit your question to show the updated stack trace. (I couldn't find anything wrong in your code)

Comment: Oh, maybe there is one problem: PDFont wordFont = currChar.getFont(); this gets a font from a PDDocument that has already been closed, isn't it?

Comment: It took me a while to be able to update to the latest build from mid October (Firewall-related problem on my machine), sorry, for the late response.
I realized the getFont() a little after posting here, too, and fixed it, but it didn't change anything. It seems this really is Font-related nevertheless: anytime an unsupported symbol occurs and throws an exception (it's usually UnsupportedOperationException, seldomly IllegalArgument) I get the described error. Since I have replaced the output font by a more powerful unicode font, everything's fine. Does throwing an exception close the document?

Comment: No, exceptions should not close the document.